# Negative Eonia rates

Tags: interest-rates, models

I'm curious how the current negative Eonia (Euro OverNight Index Average) rates would impact  derivatives pricing. Does it mean that if I post cash collateral to you, I also need to pay you interest?

More generally, does it mean that the classical interest-rate modelling assumption that interest rates can't go negative is now invalid?

Answer (score 1):

Eonia's negative implies parties posting collateral must also pay interest to their counterparties, which has led to calls for clarity from dealers.